# Exif makes Image Blank captured from camera

Tags: android, pdf, bitmap, camera, exif

In my app the user captures an image from the camera or gallery those images are then converted to PDF

The problem is that I tried to edit the EXIF data,because samsung devices rotates the image,

but now the PDF is blank, But the Image Shows in the ImageView but is still rotated, 
any suggestions?

here is the code for the image to PDF including the exif edditing

```
 private void PDFCreation(){
        PdfDocument document=new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo;
        PdfDocument.Page page;
        Canvas canvas;
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < list.size(); i++)  {
            pageInfo=new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(992, 1432, 1).create();
            page=document.startPage(pageInfo);
            canvas=page.getCanvas();
            image=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(i));
            image=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 980, 1420, true);
            image.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300);
            canvas.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300);

            float rotation=0;
            try {
                ExifInterface exifInterface=new ExifInterface(selectedPhoto);
                int orientation=exifInterface.getAttributeInt(TAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90: {
                        rotation=-90f;
                        break;
                    }
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180: {
                        rotation=-180f;
                        break;
                    }
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270: {
                        rotation=90f;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotation);
            Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0,
                    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);

            canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
            document.finishPage(page);
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") String directory_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/mypdf/";
        File file=new File(directory_path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp=(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")).format(new Date());
        String targetPdf=directory_path + timeStamp + ".pdf";
         filePath=new File(targetPdf);
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("main", "error " + e.toString());
            Toasty.error(this, "Error making PDF" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        document.close();
    }
```

Comment: `Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0,` You are not using the result. That should be: `image=Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0,`.

Comment: @blackapps I see what you mean now, How can I implement the rotation then?